# Writing Hash of Hash

Tags: perl, hash, hashmap

I have a hash containing this value.

Name of hash is PG_HASH

```
    {
      'PG_3' => {
                  'REFUND' => '-53702.00',
                  'PAYMENT' => '1122787.00'
                },
      'PG_1' => {
                  'REFUND' => '-72569.00',
                  'PAYMENT' => '1112523.00'
                },
    }
```

Other than this I also have an array that contains value related to hash.

```
@array = {
    pg_id => $pg_id,
    sum_type => $sum_type,
    sum_total => $sum_total,
    payment_ref => $payment_ref,
    payment_gateway => $payment_gateway
};
```

Now I want to write a CSV file with headers:

```
Pg_id  TYPE    Sumtotal   TYPE1    Sumtotal
1      REFUND  -72569.00  PAYMENT  1112523.00
3      REFUND  -53702.00  PAYMENT  1122787.00
```

I am unable to write the files in single row.
I tried iterating over the parent hash but unable to match that with array.

Help

Comment: Show the code where you tried, then it will be easier to help you fix your code.

Comment: I tried my %write_hash = ();
%write_hash = (%pg_id_hash,@list_query);
#print Dumper(\%write_hash);
while ( ($key, $value) = each %{$write_hash{$pg_id_hash}}){
        while ( ($key1, $value1) = each %key){
                print "Inner key is $key1 and value is $value1\n";      
                $writer->add_row([$key->{pg_id},$invoice->{$key{pg_id}->{$type}}]);
        }
}

Comment: `@array = { ... };` doesn't make much sense. Why assign a single scalar to an array?

Comment: ug, that comment is completely unreadable. If your question is lacking, update the question itself.

Comment: I need to write some other values also in the CSV which are stored in a array

Comment: Also please explain how `@array` applies to your hash.  How are they supposed to be used?  Will `$pg_id` for example have value "PG_3"?

Comment: yes...while writing into the hash ..we also write the values into array.
There are multiple values that needs to be written into CSV but we are not assigning al into the hash. Instead storing some in array.

Comment: scrap the above question completely and give us the code that is writing the CSV file

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Perl6::Form;

my %PG_HASH = (
    'PG_3' => {
        'REFUND'  => '-53702.00',
        'PAYMENT' => '1122787.00'
    },
    'PG_1' => {
        'REFUND'  => '-72569.00',
        'PAYMENT' => '1112523.00'
    },
);
my @array = (
    {
        pg_id           => 1,
        sum_type        => 'imaginary',
        sum_total       => '1000000.00',
        payment_ref     => 'imag',
        payment_gateway => '.us'
    },
    {
        pg_id           => 3,
        sum_type        => 'imaginary',
        sum_total       => '500000.00',
        payment_ref     => 'imag',
        payment_gateway => '.us'
    },
);

say "Pg_id  TYPE    Sumtotal   TYPE1    Sumtotal";
for (@array) {
  my $pg = $PG_HASH{'PG_' . $_->{pg_id}};
  print form "{<<<<} REFUND  {>>>>>>>}  PAYMENT  {>>>>>>>>}",
              $_->{pg_id}, $pg->{REFUND}, $pg->{PAYMENT};
}

say '';
say "Pg_id  TYPE      Sumtotal   TYPE1       Sumtotal";
for (keys %PG_HASH) {
  my ($id) = $_ =~ /PG_(\d+)/;
  my ($info) = grep { $_->{pg_id} == $id } @array;
  print form "{<<<<} PAYMENT  {>>>>>>>>}  SUM TOTAL  {>>>>>>>>}",
               $id, $PG_HASH{$_}{PAYMENT}, $info->{sum_total};
}
```

Output:

```
Pg_id  TYPE    Sumtotal   TYPE1    Sumtotal
1      REFUND  -72569.00  PAYMENT  1112523.00
3      REFUND  -53702.00  PAYMENT  1122787.00

Pg_id  TYPE      Sumtotal   TYPE1       Sumtotal
3      PAYMENT  1122787.00  SUM TOTAL   500000.00
1      PAYMENT  1112523.00  SUM TOTAL  1000000.00
```

[Perl6::Form](https://metacpan.org/module/Perl6%3a%3aForm) produces your formatted output (which is not CSV output).  Follow that link to learn to do more with it than I do here.

This code shows both looping over the array with reference to the hash, and looping over the keys of the hash with reference to the array.

*This code is also awful.*

First, it references the hash by generating keys: `'PG_' . $_->{pg_id}`.  It shouldn't be able to do this.  The hash shouldn't have keys like this.  If keyed by the pg_id directly, (so, a key of `1` rather than `'PG_1'`), the loop would read:

```
for (@array) {
  my $id = $_->{pg_id};
  print form "{<<<<} REFUND  {>>>>>>>}  PAYMENT  {>>>>>>>>}",
              $id, $PG_HASH{$id}{REFUND}, $PG_HASH{$id}{PAYMENT};
}
```

Second, it references the array by searching its entirety (for multiple potential results rather than a single result) for every key of the hash.  Probably `@array` should be a hash, or you should be processing it (i.e., using the first loop) rather than looking up its entries.

Third... a hash with 'hash' in the name?  An array named `@array`?  I trust that these aren't the real names.  Anyway, *better code can be written given more knowledge about where your data is coming from*.  For instance if you're populating `%PG_HASH` from a database query, and then receiving `@array` as a stream of records, then you should extract `3` from the database's `PG_3` before you add to the hash, and you should loop over the array rather than the keys of the hash.